# Compare two dependent Flux lists in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am working on solution where I need to do attach one entity data with other entity without doing SQL Join Calls ( micro services ). So I need to fetch one entity, then collect all foreign keys data from that list, then do another fetch call ( IN SQL query ) to another entity for this list. Finally I need to compare and set relation second entity details to first. I can not use either of SQL Join and JPA relationships as Project is reactive ( Web Flux and R2DBC ) and require independent services.

So let first entity is `User ( id, name, roleId )`   AND second entity is `Role (id, name )` AND I need to do findAll Users call where role object must be attached with each user.

I tried various approaches but unable to do this, As I am quite new to Reactive Programming, This is one of code which able to fetch correct data,  but second query ( getting roles ) is executing multiple times instead of single time.

```
Flux<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
    return users
        .switchIfEmpty(Flux.empty())
        .flatMap(userData -> {
            UserDto userDto = userMapper.userToUserDto(userData);

            return user
                .map(userData1 -> userData.getRoleId())
                .collectList()
                .flatMapMany(roleRepository::findByIdIn)
                .flatMap(roleDto -> {
                    if( userDto.getRoleId() == roleDto.getId() ) {
                        userDto.setRole(roleDto);
                    }
                    return Flux.just(userDto);
                });
        });
```

Comment: I see several problems in the code example, but I'm curious is there a single problem that you try solve? I mean, it seems that the code is a result of a series of experiments and that's why it looks like that, but what was the main issue?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `flatMap` you have single instance of user. If you want to invoke `roleRepository::findByIdIn`, you need to get roleIds first like this:

```
Flux<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
List<Integer> roleIds = users
    .switchIfEmpty(Flux.empty())
    .map(User::getRoleId)
    .collectList();
Map<Integer, Role> roleIdToRoles = roleRepository.findByIdIn(roleIds)
      .collectMap(Role::getId, role -> role).block();
Flux<UserDto> userDtos = users
    .switchIfEmpty(Flux.empty())
    .map(user -> {
        UserDto userDto = userMapper.userToUserDto(user);
        RoleDTO roleDto = roleIdToRoles.get(userDto.getRoleId);
        userDto.setRole(roleDto);
        return userDto;
    };
```

Comment: This solution uses "block", I also find suggestion for this for another SO question, but that is not something I want to do in reactive program. I am searching for pure reactive solution.  Which do not block in between of reactive program. But thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want something like this:

```
Flux<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
return users
    .flatMap(userData -> {
        UserDto userDto = userMapper.userToUserDto(userData);
        roleRepository
            // assuming it returns one role per user, i.e. Mono<Role>
            .fingByIdIn(userData.getRoleId())
            .map(roleDto -> {
               //assuming fingByIdIn always returns a correct role
               userDto.setRole(roleDto)
               userDto
            })
            // if role not found return w/o it
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(userDto)
    });
```